# Failed to add linker flag to rust project

Tags: rust, linker, linker-errors, rust-cargo

I want to link the rust project with the flag `--no-relax`.

Here is what I tried:

1. First try:

```
RUSTFLAGS="--cfg aes_force_soft --cfg polyval_force_soft -Clink-args="-Wl,--no-relax"" CARGO_TARGET_DIR=../target cargo xbuild --target x86_64-qkernel.json  --verbose
```

As you can see, I do get `-Clink-args=-Wl,--no-relax` during rustc compilation

```
Running `rustc --crate-name qkernel src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type staticlib --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C panic=abort -C lto -C codegen-units=1 -C debuginfo=0 -C metadata=97ea9ce0f16c5783 -C extra-filename=-97ea9ce0f16c5783 --out-dir /home/yaoxin/master-thesis-quark/qkernel/../target/x86_64-qkernel/release/deps --target /home/yaoxin/master-thesis-quark/qkernel/x86_64-qkernel.json -L dependency=/home/yaoxin/master-thesis-quark/qkernel/../target/x86_64-qkernel/release/deps -L dependency=/home/yaoxin/master-thesis-quark/qkernel/../target/release/deps --extern aes_gcm=/home/yaoxin/master-thesis-quark/qkernel/../target/x86_64-qkernel/release/deps/libaes_gcm-717643e861007e33.rlib b --cfg aes_force_soft --cfg polyval_force_soft -Clink-args=-Wl,--no-relax
```

But I still get the flowing error

```
Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 1m 05s
ld: failed to convert GOTPCREL relocation; relink with --no-relax
make[1]: *** [makefile:20: ../build/qkernel.bin] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yaoxin/master-thesis-quark/qkernel'
make: *** [makefile:5: release] Error 2
```

It seems like the compiler doesn't recognize the flag, any idea how I should pass the flag to the compiler?

Comment: Might be that you need to escape the inner `"`: `RUSTFLAGS="--cfg aes_force_soft --cfg polyval_force_soft -Clink-args=\"-Wl,--no-relax\""`

Comment: No, it doesn't work, in this case, I got `rustc ..... '-Clink-args="-Wl,--no-relax"' `, and I still get the same error message